# Is it possible to dynamically generate the options of the angular-ui tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor through the [ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) Angular directive.

```
<textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="email.body"></textarea>
```

I can't initialise the editor with the `content_css` option set to a value which is obtained from an XHR request because the `link` function of the directive is called before the callback of the XHR request. As a consequence of this, the options are not passed to the directive.

```
Template.get({ id: $routeParams.id }, function(response) {
  $scope.template = response.attributes;

  $scope.tinymceOptions = {
      inline: false,
      plugins : 'code importcss preview code',
      skin: 'lightgray',
      theme : 'modern',
      content_css: $scope.template.content_css
    };
});
```

If I broadcast a `$tinymce:refresh` event after initialising the options, the editor gets re-initialised with the new options, but the old editor is not removed.

I a have little experience in angular directives, is it possible to watch changes in the options and reflect them in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the options you load asynchronously and display the editor only after you got them. Proof of concept:

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-if="!tinymceOptions">Please wait, we're initliazing editor for you!</div>
    <div ng-if="tinymceOptions">
        <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="email.body"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And controller:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    Template.get({ id: $routeParams.id }, function(response) {
        // your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice one, but the problem with this solution is that the user can change the options several times by loading different templates.

Comment: You can add a flag to the scope, i.e. `tinyMceChangingConfig`. Use it in `ng-if` and set it to `false` when user changes configuration and back to `true` when configuration is fetched.